Preventing Blank SSRS Reports from Emailing for parameterized reports that go out to multiple recipients
We use SSRS 2019 Enterprise edition for monitoring business metrics and setting up email alerts. These reports are blank at time when the alert conditions are not met.
We intend to offer these alerts to more users as a self-serve option and also prevent emails from going out when the alert is blank.
At the moment we achieve this using 3 methods depending on data source of the report and delivery render format (Excel or MHTML). But none of these methods are clean and scalable when it comes to managing multiple subscriptions on a single report, each with different report parameter filter values and recipient list.
1. Raise error in query:
When the report runs off SQL Server data source, raise an error using the code below that subsequently stalls SSRS subscription and no email is sent out
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM #temp_table_report_output
)
RAISERROR ('NO RECORDS FOUND',16,1)
ELSE
(
    SELECT * FROM #temp_table_report_output
)

2. Combination of NoRowsMessage in SSRS and Outlook email rule:
Data sources other that SQL Server don't support raising error in query. In such cases, add a NoRowsMessage in SSRS report with specific words such as 'Empty Email' and then add a email rule in Outlook that looks for those specific words in email (and also From email address) to send those emails to Junk folder
3. Data-driven subscriptions:
When the report delivery is Excel attachment, the NoRowsMessage shows up inside the excel attachment rendering #2 solution useless. Also it's not really a good practice in first place when other users are involved.
In such cases, add a Data-driven subscription that checks for any records in the report output and only then returns recipient email addresses.
Some threads also suggest using Stored Procedures to achieve this, but that's applicable only for SQL server as the data source.
Also #3 mentioned above seems to be the ultimate solution but it's not scalable. For reports which have parameter filters and 20 different users are supposed to receive alerts with different combinations of parameter values and recipients, it simply becomes impossible to manage these subscriptions without making an error.

How about designing a data driven-subscription such that the recipient list is retrieved from a view that only returns such recipients where the desired parameters generate data?
